# Splunk query to Table

Tags: splunk

I have a Splunk query that returns something like:

```
t=something; l=something_else; Rule Flow with data {"path": "some/path", "response": {...}...}
```

I am trying to get a table of the data elements inside the "response" object which is inside this outer object. When I add this:

```
|
table t, l
```

I get those elements (t and l) in a table just fine but I'm not sure how to access the objects. I have tried using all combinations of "Rule Flow with data" as the key but no luck.

Comment: Only extracted or calculated fields can be displayed by the `table` command. The `t` and `l` fields are extracted automatically because they are in k=v format.  The other fields have to be extracted using the `rex` or `spath` command or some other method.

Comment: what *specific* SPL have you tried when you say you've `tried using all combinations of "Rule Flow with data"`?